# Enviar mensagem via WhatsApp para um contato específico

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent

Estou tentando enviar uma mensagem de texto via WhatsApp para um número previamente selecionado. O chat do contato abre, mas a mensagem contida nos `Extras` não aparece no campo de texto. Vejam:

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("smsto:" + "55" + (number));
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionSendto, uri);
i.PutExtra("sms_body", "Instale meu novo aplicativo!");
i.SetPackage("com.whatsapp");
StartActivity(i);
```

PS.: nenhuma exceção é lançada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui achar um meio que funciona:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
sendIntent.PutExtra("jid", "55" + (number) + "@s.whatsapp.net");
sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "Instale meu novo aplicativo!");
sendIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
sendIntent.SetPackage("com.whatsapp");
sendIntent.SetType("text/plain");
StartActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=559599111111";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```